# do CUDA events time cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy executions?

Tags: cuda, gpu, cpu-usage, nvidia, timing

I am using the following code to time calls to `cudaMalloc()`. I am curious: Do CUDA events only time our kernels, or they also time the "in-built kernels". In other words, is the following method for timing `cudaMalloc()` valid?

```
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);
cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
for(int t =0 ; t < 100 ; t++){
    float* test;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&test, 3000000 * sizeof(float));
    cudaFree(test);
}
cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
float elapsedTime; 
cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime , start, stop);
printf("time elapsed on the GPU: %f ms", elapsedTime/100);
```

Answer (score 2):

cu(da)EventRecord() does nothing more than submit a command to the GPU that tells the GPU to write a timestamp when the GPU processes the command.  The timestamp is just an onboard high-resolution counter.  So CUDA events are most useful when used as an asynchronous mechanism for timing on-GPU events, like how long a specific kernel takes to run.  CUDA memory management mostly happens on the CPU, so CUDA events are not ideal for timing CUDA allocation and free operations.

In short: You're better off using CPU-based timing like gettimeofday().

Comment: But does it time the cudaMalloc? Put another way, when only the time for the kernel execution is wanted, should one ensure that nothing else, like cudaMalloc, cudaMemcpy, or cudaFree are called between the first cudaEventRecord and the second?

Comment: Asynchronous CUDA memcpy's are fair game, but cudaMalloc()/cudaFree() may stall the GPU while the driver messes around with page tables. The CUDA events will still happily record timing as described in the answer, but their timing information won't be as useful.